# How do I connect to MySQL on Kubernetes with DBeaver directly instead of using kubectl port-forward?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, dbeaver

Currently connecting to MySQL on Kubernetes with DBeaver after run the following command on terminal.

```
kubectx arn:aws:eks:XXX:cluster/XXX && kubens XXX && kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 XXX 13306:3306
```

I am looking for a way to do port-forwarding directly on DBeaver, as it is tedious to run the command every time and then connect with DBeaver.

What are some possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to run kubectl port-forward before connecting automatically.

1. Create a directory 'dbeaver-scripts' with a subfolder 'before-connect'.
2. Create a shell-script, I named it my database connections name 'database-name.sh'
3. Example shell script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH='' # note that you need to set you path to include all dependencies default path of the dbeaver shell contains almost nothing.
echo "connect to database-name"
aws sso login --profile your-profile
kubectx arn:aws:eks:XXX:cluster/XXX 
kubens XXX
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 XXX 13306:3306
echo "connection closed"
```

4. Give the script excution rights `chmod +x database-name.sh`
5. Test script by running it via your terminal.

   - If your script works in terminal but not in dbeaver; please echo your PATH 'echo $PATH' and copy it over into your script. As dbeaver's shell is pretty minimal on what it includes in its PATH.
6. Edit your db connection its configuration.
   In the UI you will find a 'Shell commands' tab which has a setting
   called 'Before connect'.
7. set the working directory to the before-connect folder
8. set the command to
   `/bin/bash -c "./database-name.sh"`
9. Pause before connecting for the amount of seconds you need for your script to run (I set it to a safe 10000ms)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible at the moment

But they do have an new issue who is open about that: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/15242